# Copy all rows between two time values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with about 6000 rows and in column Z there is a date and time value. The formatting looks like this:

```
2020-01-29  13:18:36
```

I want to copy and paste all the row between Now and 30 minutes back. For example if the current time is 08:00 I want to copy all the rows from "2020-01-30  07:30:00" to "2020-01-30  08:00:00".

Something like this is what I have in mind:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<=Now", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=">=Now-30 minutes"
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")
```

How do I get the current time formatted like the example above and the time 30 minutes back and how do I insert it in to AutoFilter?

Thanks in advance!

/Jens

Edit:

This code works:

```
Dim LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("privata").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("privata").Range("A1:AN" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:=">=2020-01-30  08:00", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=2020-01-30  08:30"
Sheets("privata").Range("A1:AN" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("toptre").Range("A1")
Sheets("privata").ShowAllData
```

But this doesn't:

```
Dim Nu As Date
Dim PreNu As Date
Dim LastRow
Nu = Now
PreNu = Now - 1 / 48
LastRow = Sheets("privata").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("privata").Range("A1:AN" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<=" & Nu, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=">=" & PreNu
Sheets("privata").Range("A1:AN" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("toptre").Range("A1")
Sheets("privata").ShowAllData
```

Here's an example of the table:
[image]

Comment: Well you'd start with the function `Now`. To add 30 minutes, you could always just add `.5/24` or `1/48` or use `DateAdd`.

Comment: Not sure if you'll need to `Format` them.

Comment: Variables shouldn't fall inside the quotes. Concatenate them with `&`: `">=" & Nu`. Not sure if you'll need to `Format`.

Comment: I tried it but got the same error.

Comment: Did you fix `"<=PreNu"` too?

Comment: Yes I fixed both.

Comment: You got the operators mixed up: `<=` for `Nu` and `>=` for `PreNu`.

Comment: Got the same result.

Comment: Tried to hard code it.

Comment: Sheets("privata").AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:=">=2020-01-30  08:00", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=2020-01-30  08:30"

Comment: But got the same result.

Comment: `Sheets` doesn't have `AutoFilter` method, you need to point it to a range. Try e.g. `Sheets("privata").Range("A1:Z17").AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<=" & Nu, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=">=" & PreNu`. The same goes for the last line (specify the range before copying the values).

Comment: @JustynaMK - good catch! although a `Worksheet` does have an [`AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.autofilter) property but that's not what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen & sorry for jumping the queue, you basically solved the whole thread all by yourself :)

Comment: No you didn't jump at all. That was definitely a valuable contribution. Once this is all sorted out feel free to post an answer and I'll upvote. @JustynaMK - some rep coming your way if you answer :)

Comment: Thank you! It works now! I added the range and it copied the rows beautifully! :)

Comment: Glad it all worked! Thanks guys :$

Comment: Sorry wait! It didn't work... Only the hard coded version worked. When I tried the <=Nu version nothing got copied. I got no errors but nothing got copied.

Comment: I tried the variables and Nu gave me the current time, formatted exactly as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. PreNu gave me the same time minus 30 minutes. So it should be working...

Comment: The filter is working, it filters out the rows between now and 30 min back. What's not working is the line that copies the data. It only copies the header!

Answer (score 1):

As per the commentary section, `Sheets` doesn't have `AutoFilter` method, causing `Named argument not found` error. You need to specify your `Range` before applying the rest of your code (which was improved thanks to @BigBen's contribution).

[image]

Correct syntax:

```
Sheets("privata").Range("A1:Z17").AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<=" & Nu, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=">=" & PreNu
Sheets("privata").Range("A1:Z17").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("toptre").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Technically `Sheets("privata")` is a `Worksheet` - so "Sheets" doesn't have an `AutoFilter` method is true but we're dealing with the singular here (a member of the collection, not the entire collection). Anyway, thanks again for the contribution, upvoted.

Comment: Eh I learned it from someone else, just passing on the knowledge :-)